# Active Record query causing SQLException near "," syntax error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I'm trying to display all such rows of a table STUDENTS which have a value of an attribute, such as `COURSE IN` a set of given values e.g. `'MS', 'PhD'`.

I get the values in the students_controller.rb file using `params`. I tried to run an Active Record query using `where` to do the job:

```
@all_courses = ['MS', 'PhD', 'BA', 'MSc']

@students = Student.where("course IN :courses" , {:courses => params.has_key?(:courses) ? params[:courses].keys : @all_courses})
```

But I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "students".* FROM "students"  WHERE (course IN 'MS', 'PhD', 'BA', 'MSc')
```

I think the error might be due to the absence of ; at the end of the SQL query generated by Active Record, but I cannot do anything to get that semicolon at the end.

Comment: I think you need parentheses around the values of your `IN` clause, something like `SELECT "students".* FROM "students"  WHERE course IN ('MS', 'PhD', 'BA', 'MSc')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use parentheses: `"course IN (:courses)"`